# How to use mysqldump, pv, and zip command together?

Tags: linux, zip, mysql, progress

I want to use `mysqldump` to get a table from a remote MySQL server, then compress this downloaded file using `zip`. While downloading, I wish I can view the progress using `pv`.

Can I do the above things with `|` in one line of command?

These are what I've tried:

```
mysqldump -uuser_name -ppassword -hremote_address --routines my_database my_table | pv | zip > my_database_my_table.sql.zip
```

The problem with this command is that when executing `unzip my_database_my_table.sql.zip`, I got `-` as the name of the output file. I wish I could determine the file's name when I execute `zip` command.

Is it possible to set the name of the inflated file?

```
mysqldump -uuser_name -ppassword -hremote_address --routines my_database my_table | pv | zip my_database_my_table.sql > my_database_my_table.sql.zip
```

This command gives me `mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write` error.

Comment: I think not possible with zip command. This work, mysqldump -uuser_name -ppassword -hremote_address --routines my_database my_table | pv | bzip2 -c > my_database_my_table.sql.bz2 sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I used them together:

```
mysqldump -u db_user -pdb_password db_name| pv | zip > backup.zip
```

Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985546/3778130 full automatic backup script if someone is interested.

Hope it helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 0):

A quick `man zip` shows that you can use -O or --output-file to specify the output name. That should do you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to get the progress out of `pv`, it needs to know the full size of the data. Unfortunately, by piping it to `mysqldump` it does not have that kind of data.

I would recommend to dump the data first and transfer and restore it later.

1. Dump it.
2. `pv mysqldump.sql | zip > ~/mysqldump.sql.zip`
3. `scp remotehost:/home/folder/mysqldump.sql ./`
4. unzip it
5. `pv mysqldump.sql | mysql -u<dbuser> -p <dbname>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with pv, but my zip documentation states for zip to use the stdin, the dash must be specified. So i use this :

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password mydatabase | zip mydatabase.zip -
```