# Shell script mysqldump not executing properly from cron

Tags: mysql, shell, cron

I have a shell script that I got from trante's answer in:

[Linux shell script for database backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664893/linux-shell-script-for-database-backup)

The script runs correctly from the command line and creates the mysql backup.

However when it runs from a cron job the script executes and creates a the mysqldump file but the file is empty.

I have tried setting the PATH environment in the script but nothing I have tried works.

Regards

EDIT:

Adding script

```
#!/bin/sh
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
filename="db_backup_$now".gz
backupfolder="/mybackupfolder"
fullpathbackupfile="$backupfolder/$filename"
logfile="$backupfolder/"backup_log_"$(date +'%Y_%m')".txt
echo "mysqldump started at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
mysqldump --user=myuser --password=mypassword --default-character-set=utf8 mydatabase | gzip > "$fullpathbackupfile"
echo "mysqldump finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
chown myuser "$fullpathbackupfile"
chown myuser "$logfile"
echo "file permission changed" >> "$logfile"
find "$backupfolder" -name db_backup_* -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \;
echo "old files deleted" >> "$logfile"
echo "operation finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
echo "*****************" >> "$logfile"
exit 0
```

Comment: Why -1 without leaving a comment?

Comment: Because if you need help to debug a script, then don't paste link of a entire post (even not linked to the good answer) but code **as text** in **your original post**

Comment: ok I will now edit question

Comment: If you don't have time to spend to provide full informations, not sure you will get any help. You tell about fixing PATH, but **nothing related here**

Comment: Not a question of time. I spent hours already ;). I have tried adding this to the script: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin and other variants like PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/pathToMyScript

Comment: I just meant that it doesnt seem related to the PATH as the script executes. But the mysqldump part doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.

You have to put the path to mysql in the following line:

```
mysqldump --user=myuser --password=mypassword..
```

Which in my case is:

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user=myuser --password=mypassword..
```